# Builder pattern - configuration file reading

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm facing a design problem. I want to separate building objects with a builder pattern, but the problem is that objects have to be built from configuration file.

So far I have decided that all objects, created from configuration, will be stored in DataContext class (container for all objects), because these objects states will be updated from a transmission (so it's easier to have them in one place).

I'm using external library for reading from XML file - and my question is how to hide it - is it better to inject it to concreteBuilder class? I have to notice that builder class will have to create lots of objects and at the end - connect them between each other.

Base class could look like that:

```
/*
 * IDataContextBuilder
 * base class for building data context object
 * and sub obejcts
 */
class IDataContextBuilder {
public:
    /*
     * GetResult()
     * returns result of building process
     */
    virtual DataContext * GetResult () = 0;
    /*
     * Virtual destructor
     */
    virtual ~IDataContextBuilder() {    }
};

class ConcreteDataContextBuilder {
public:
     ConcreteDataContextBuilder(pugi::xml_node & rootNode);
     DataContext * GetResult ();
}
```

How to implement it correctly? What could be better pattern to build classes from configuration files?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a problem with that, but maybe you could inject another 'Director' class that receives a specific builder, loads the config files, and produces objects calling the respective builder-subclasses.

What I mean:

```
class DataContextDirector {
public:
    void SetBuilder(IDataContextBuilder* builder);

    void SetConfig(const std::string& configFilePath); // or whatever

    DataContext* ProduceObject() {
        // pseudo-code here:
        // myBuilder->setup(xmlNodeOfConfig);
        // return myBuilder->GetResult();
    }
};
```